# All control are fired in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

since I am new to ASP .NET I wonder whether this is normal behavior or something strange. I am trying to convert C# WinForms app to web app and it is behaving not as I expected.

In desktop app I get data after user press enter on textbox. Data are loaded I can modify it and then, when I am done changing data I can press one of two buttons and data are saved to database or form is cleared. Something like this.

```
    private int idOrder;

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(load_data)
       {
           label1.Text = "some loaded data";
           ...
           else{ MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong. No data loaded");
       }


    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           //save to database;
    }
```

But When I try to do the same in ASP.NET Web form, whenever I press enter on textbox all controls are fired (as it is written in source code line after line) when page is refreshed. Could you please advice we what should I do to replicate same behavior as in winforms e.g. user input - enter - load data - modify - press button when I want. Thank you.

//Is the view state thing I am looking for?

Comment: Look into into ispostback.  Also, please include sample code that is not working.

Comment: This is a helpful MSDN page about ASP.Net page lifecycles.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx  As @Trey said, surrounding code that should not execute on postback with `if(!Page.isPostBack)` could help, but I'm not sure exactly what the problem is.

Comment: You can't use the MessageBox class in ASP.NET. That's specific to Windows forms.

Comment: share your code

Comment: Thank you as well for your response. I definitely do have to read more about this. And I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet to get you started. Keep in mind that posting a HTML form when pressing enter is default behavior for websites. So the first thing is preventing that by wrapping the TextBox and Submit Button with a `Panel` with a `DefaultButton` assigned to it. Now when the enter is pressed in `TextBox1`, it will post the form as `dummyButton`

Next we add an `OnTextChanged` event to `TextBox1` and set `AutoPostBack` to `true`. This will fire when the focus of `TextBox1` is lost. You could remove this and just use the enter with `dummyButton`.

The `dummyButton` is added to ensure the form will PostBack when enter is pressed in `TextBox1` to get the desired behaviour.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="dummyButton" runat="server" OnClick="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>
```

And then in code behind.

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //load from database
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //save to database
    Label1.Text = "Data saved!";
    TextBox1.Text = "";
}
```

You can also prevent PostBack with enter like this. The JavaScript will block all enters. Depending on your page design you could set this in the `<body>` tag for example.

```
<div onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It solves my problem. It seems there is a lot to study for me :)